# const vs non-const of container and its content

Tags: c++, constants, containers

With a container class, such as `std::vector`, there are two different concepts of constant-ness: that of the container (i.e. its size) and that of the elements. It seems that `std::vector` confuses these two, such that the following simple code won't compile:

```
struct A {
  A(size_t n) : X(n) {}
  int&x(int i) const { return X[i]; }    // error: X[i] is non-const.
private:
  std::vector<int> X;
};
```

Note that even though the *data members* (the three pointers to the begin&end of the data and the end of the allocated buffer) of `std::vector` are **not** changed by a call to its `operator[]`, this member is not `const` -- isn't this a strange design?

Note also that for raw pointers, these two concepts of constant-ness are neatly separated, such that the corresponding raw-pointer code

```
struct B {
  B(size_t n) : X(new int[n]) {}
  ~B() { delete[] X; }
  void resize(size_t n);                 // non-const
  int&x(int i) const { return X[i]; }    // fine
private:
  int*X;
};
```

works just fine.

So what is the correct/recommended way to deal with this when using `std::vector` (without using `mutable`)?

Is a `const_cast<>` as in

```
int&A::x(int i) const { return const_cast<std::vector<int>&>(X)[i]; }
```

deemed acceptable (`X` is known to be non-`const`, so no UB here)?

**EDIT** just to prevent further confusion: I do want to modify the elements, i.e. the *contents of the container but not the container itself* (the size and/or memory location).

Comment: The data of `std::vector` could be changed by your call to `operator[]`. As you've writen `A::X`, `a.x(1)++;` is perfectly legal, and modifies the contents of the vector.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The *contents* of a vector are not its actual *data* (though you may logically associated them as such). If you inspect `std::vector`, it has only 3 pointers as data (begin&end of data and end of buffer). These remain unchanged.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

C++ only supports one level of `const`.  As far as the compiler
is concerned, it is bitwise const: the "bits" actually in the
object (i.e. counted in `sizeof`) cannot be modified without
playing games (`const_cast`, etc.), but anything else is fair
game.  In the early days of C++ (late 1980s, early 1990s) there
was a lot of discussion as to the design advantages of bitwise
const vs. logical const (also known as Humpty-Dumpty const,
because as Andy Koenig once told me, when the programmer uses
`const`, it means exactly what the programmer wants it to mean).
The consensus finally coalesced in favor of logical const.

This does mean that authors of container classes have to make
a choice.  Are the elements of the container part of the
container, or not.  If they're part of the container, then they
cannot be modified if the container is const.  There's no way to
offer a choice; the author of the container has to choose one or
the other.  Here too, there seems to be a consensus: the
elements are part of the container, and if the container is
const, they cannot be modified.  (Perhaps the parallel with
C style arrays played a role here; if a C style array is const,
then you cannot modify any of its elements.)

Like you, I've encountered times when I wanted to forbid
modification of the size of the vector (perhaps to protect
iterators), but not of its elements.  There are no really
satisfactory solutions; the best I can think of is to create
a new type, which contains a `mutable std::vector`, and provide
forwarding functions which correspond to the meaning of `const`
I need in this specific case.  And if you want to distinguish
three levels (completely const, partially const, and non-const),
you'll need derivation.  The base class only exposes the
completely const and partially const functions (e.g. a `const
int operator[]( size_t index ) const;` and `int operator[](
size_t index );`, but not `void push_back( int );`); the
functions which allow insertion and removal of an element are
only exposed in the derived class.  Clients which shouldn't
insert or remove elements are only passed a non-const reference
to the base class.

Comment: +1 nice discussion. I'm not convinced, though, about the fact that the designer of a container class has no choice. One could implement a container class which carries the const-ness of its elements as template argument and allow move-conversion (using smart pointers) between const and non-const containers. Your base-derived design looks simpler, though.

Comment: @Walter The designer of a container class has all sorts of choices.  The designer of `std::vector` made, in this case, the one for which there seems to be a general consensus---most of the pre-standard containers I'm aware of made the same.  Globally, there doesn't seem to be a large demand for a container which offers the three levels of `const` (none, partial or complete), except in special cases (e.g. `std::array`).  (In pre-standard days, one of my array class took the size as a constructor argument, and offered no possibility of changing it later.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The explanation is excellent, however the first two  opening sentence at the very top gave the impression that bitwise const is the one that C++ supports. *(I hope there aren't too many C++ programmers who are TL;DR.)* This opening sentence is true on the compiler back-end, but the front-end only considers `const` to be a syntactic aid - it is used in type checking, that's it. (By the way, C++11 introduces compile-time `constexpr`.) Logical const-ness only exists in programmers' brains. A C++ programmer will realize the differences when one begins multi-threaded programming.

Comment: @rwong The _language_ (and its compilers) formally only supports bitwise const.  But the const is part of the type system, and when you overload on it, you can define it to mean whatever you want it to mean.  Consensus today is that the programmer should implement logical const (which the language or the compiler cannot do, because it doesn't know what is "logical" in any given context).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, unlike pointers, you can't do something like

```
std::vector<int> i;
std::vector<const int>& ref = i;
```

That's why `std::vector` can't disambiguate between the two kinds of `const` as they might apply, and it has to be conservative. I, personally, would choose to do something like

```
const_cast<int&>(X[i]);
```

Edit: As another commenter accurately pointed out, iterators *do* model this dichotomy. If you stored a `vector<int>::iterator` to the beginning, you could then de-reference it in a const method and get back a non-const `int&`. I think. But you'd have to be careful of invalidation.

Comment: The use of iterators suggests an interesting solution: a _view_ class which contains just the begin and end iterator, and provides just the limited functionality he wants.  (For that matter, a view class with a pointer to the vector would do as well.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a strange design, it's a very deliberate choice, and the right one IMHO.

Your `B` example is not a good analogy for a `std::vector`, a better analogy would be:

```
struct C {
   int& get(int i) const { return X[i]; }
   int X[N];
};
```

but with the very useful difference that the array can be resized. The code above is invalid for the same reason as your original is, the array (or `vector`) elements are conceptually "members" (technically sub-objects) of the containing type, so you should not be able to modify them through a `const` member function.

I would say the `const_cast` is not acceptable, and neither is using `mutable` unless as a last resort. You should ask why you want to change a const object's data, and consider making the member function non-const.

Comment: This is a matter of interpretation. If you view a `vector` as a C-array which is re-sizable, then I agree. However, then where do the `resize()` etc functions fit with this analogy? They must be more than constant: you want to be able to give non-const access to the elements but not to the size. This is not possible with `std::vector`. I think the usual way this is sort-of solved is to provide iterators, which typically allow to change the contents, but not the container.

Comment: It's just an analogy, don't take it too literally, anyway `resize` isn't const, so it's allowed to mutate the object. Not sure what you mean about iterators, but none of the standard containers will give you a non-const iterator to a const container.

Comment: what I meant about iterators is that if you have a (non-const) iterator you cannot modify the container. So the container remains const while the elements can be modified.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using `std::vector::at()` method instead of a `const_cast`.

Comment: The const overload of `vector::at()` returns a `const` reference, so that won't help